# Charge on parallel conducting plates

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, conductors

In this figure, where will the charge go if we have earthed both the plates? I am having some trouble figuring this. Will the charge $q$ on the first plate flow towards the Earth (Case 1), or will it induce a charge on the the second plate as in Case 2?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Can we calculate the net charge on inner surface of both the plates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every conductor connected to earth without resistance in between is on the same potential as earth itself in the equilibrium. Since both plates are connected to earth, they are thus on the same potential and there is no voltage between them. This means, your case 1 is realised: If you put charge on one of the plates, it is going to drain into earth during relaxation into the equilibrium. This is equivalent to earthing the object with which you put the charge on the plate in the first place.

As a consequence, the net charge on the inner surfaces should be 0.